# References and citations with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, brackets, nameref

I use `bibtex` for my references and I am wondering, which is the best way to organise my list and citations? There are many question about references but I can not find a way to do what I want. with `bibtex`. What I want is to have my list in alphabetical order and my citation within the text with names instead of  ref-numbers and with no square brackets. What I currently have is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \begin{document}
        \title{\vspace{-3.0cm}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\title here\\\vspace{1.0cm}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\{initial analysis}}
        \author{author \thanks{organisation}}

        \maketitle
        \newpage
        \tableofcontents
        \newpage
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
        \section{Introduction} 
        The visit to the area of interest 
        \subsection{Methods}
        In order to analyse the ....  \cite{sturrock_climate_2011}
        \subsubsection{Processing of data}
        For the analysis of out data ...
        \section{Initial results and Current work}
        Respecting the current work, ....
        \section{References}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{blb}

    \end{document}
```

My reference:

```
@article{n._sturrock_climate_2011,
        title = {Climate change and forest diseases},
        volume = {60},
        doi = {10.1111/j.1365-3059.2010.02406.x},
        abstract = {As climate changes, },
        journal = {Plant Pathology},
        author = {N. Sturrock, R and Frankel, S. and V. Brown, A and E. Hennon, P and T. Kliejunas, J and J. Lewis, K and Worrall, J. and Woods, A.},
        month = feb,
        year = {2011},
        pages = {133--149}
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Asking for the *best* way to do something is usually unhelpful, as (a) there can be several ways to achieve the "something" and (b) it may not be obvious how to rank the possible ways, at least not unambiguously. Basically, are you asking what it takes to (a) generate authoryear-style citation call-outs and (b) have the bibliographic entries sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames? Please confirm.

Comment: Incidentally, the `author` field of the entry you posted appears to be messed up: Almost every author seems to have a first initial both before and after the surname. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico, I do have my reference list in alphabetical order so I ask to have authoryear-style citation call-outs as you say, within my text without the square brackets. With the above code, I only get te number of reference in citations. I understand that there are many ways and that is why I ask for suggestion. Apologies if it is not the right way.

Comment: As regards the name, I use zotero for my bibliography this is the format I have. All my references are similar to this one which appears as R. N. Sturrock, S. Frankel, A. V. Brown, P. Hennon, J. T.
Kliejunas, K. J. Lewis, J. J. Worrall, and A. J. Woods. Climate change and forest diseases. Plant Pathology. 60: 133#149 , 60:133#149, 2011.

Comment: Relying on Zotero to produce valid BibTeX code may be unwarranted. For instance, the example you gave in the second comment fails to use the keyword `and` to separate authors and, instead, uses `,` (comma) inappropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate authoryear-style citation call-outs, it's necessary to (a) employ a bibliography style that's capable of producing such call-outs -- fortunately, `apalike` is such a style -- and (b) employ a suitable citation management package. For instance, since you're using the `apalike` bibliography style, loading the `natbib` package and using `\citet` and `\citep` will let you achieve your objective.

A comment about the `author` field: Use the keyword `and` to separate authors. Use commas if you wish to place given names *after* rather than before the surname.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{blb.bib}
@article{sturrock_climate_2011,
  author       = "Sturrock, R. N. and Frankel, S. J. and
                  Brown, A. V. and Hennon, P. E. and
                  Kliejunas, J. T. and Lewis, K. J. and
                  Worrall, J. J. and Woods, A. J.",
  title        = "Climate change and forest diseases",
  journal      = "Plant Pathology",
  year         = 2011,
  volume       = "60",
  number       = "1",
  pages        = "133-149",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\citet{sturrock_climate_2011}, 
\citep{sturrock_climate_2011}

\bibliography{blb}
\end{document}
```